# Query better-sqlite3 for record data

Tags: node.js, discord.js, better-sqlite3

So I have a table called `logging` in my database, with a schema of `guildid & channel`

I need to get the contents of `channel` if the `guildid` matches, I ran `console.log(logs)` to see what was actually happening and it said `{ channel: '495602952778678274' }`

I opted to leave the complete code so you can clearly see what I am trying to accomplish.

```
client.on('messageDelete', async (message) => {
  const logs = sql.prepare(`SELECT channel FROM logging WHERE guildid = ${message.guild.id};`).get();
  console.log(logs);
  if (!logs) return;
  const entry = await message.guild.fetchAuditLogs({
    type: 'MESSAGE_DELETE'
  }).then(audit => audit.entries.first());
  let user = "";
  if (entry.extra.channel.id === message.channel.id &&
    (entry.target.id === message.author.id) &&
    (entry.createdTimestamp > (Date.now() - 5000)) &&
    (entry.extra.count >= 1)) {
    user = entry.executor.username;
  } else {
    user = message.author.username;
  }
  client.channels.get(logs).send(`A message was deleted in ${message.channel.name} by ${user}`);
});
```

I also tried just `logs.send...` and finally I tried

```
const id = sql.prepare(`SELECT channel FROM logging WHERE guildid = ${message.guild.id};`).get();
const logs = client.channels.get(id);
client.channels.get(logs).send('Send a message');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you did `console.log(logs)` and it gave `{ channel: '495602952778678274' }` then you should do:

```
const result = sql.prepare(`SELECT channel FROM logging WHERE guildid = ${message.guild.id};`).get();
const logs = client.channels.get(result.channel);
logs.send('Send a message');
```